# Command line not accepting commands

Tags: magento2, command-line

When I run any M2 command line scripts I get the follow error message:

```
Command line user does not have read and write permissions on var/generation directory.  Please address this issue before using Magento command line.
```

My user is a part of the group with admin rights and the file owner.

May I ask where else to check?

Comment: in your command line run chmod g+s var/generation which should give you the access you need

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it's a file permission error.
In case if you are ubuntu user, then you can run the following commands:

```
cd /path/to/magento2/
sudo chmod -R 777 var/
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data var/
```

Comment: The user "www-data" does not exist.  Is that a separate issue?